# Minimal & characteristic equation and $f(A)=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra

A question was given : Q) a $3 \times 3$ real idempotent matrix $A$ is diagonalizable. Prove or disprove. Somewhere I have found an answer to the above question which states:-

Since $A$ satisfies the equation $x(x-1)=0$ therefore its minimal polynomial is a factor of $x(x-1)$ and consequently is a product of distinct linear factor & hence diagonalizable.  I am not totally sure whether this logic is true or not.This  answer(right or wrong whatever) leads to an query which is:- Is it true that if a real $n \times n$ $A$ satisfies a real polynomial equation $f(x)=0$ then $m(x)$ divides $f(x)$; $m(x)$ being the minimal polynomial, or is there any relation between $f(x)$ & $ch(x)$ or between $f(x)$ & $m(x)$; $ch(x)$ being the characteristic polynomial of the matrix. Someone please help.

Comment: Try starting with the definitions of the minimal and characteristic polynomials and see where that leads.

Comment: I edited your question the make the $\LaTeX$ work and to fix a few other small things.  Cheers!

Comment: Is your major uncertainty for the field of reals? Because for $\mathbb C$ it is true. Note that for idempotent matrix the eigenvalues are real, so there is no trouble with real diagonalization.

Answer (score 2):

That reasoning is correct. But (luckily, since based on parts of your question it sounds like you're not entirely clear on what the minimal polynomial is and its basic properties) this  special case is simpler than that.

Given $x\in\mathbb R^3$, let $y=x-Tx$ and $z=Tx$, so $$x=y+z.$$ You can use $T^2=T$ to show that $y$ and $z$ are both eigenvectors of $T$. So $\mathbb R^3$ is spanned by the eigenspaces of $T$, which is the basic criterion for diagonalizability.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if an $n \times n$ matrix satisfyes $P(A)=0$ then $m_A(X) |P(X)$.

The reason for this is the following:

$$I:= \{ Q(X) : Q(A)=0 \}$$
is an ideal in $\mathbb R[X]$, which is a PID. The minimal polynomial is defined as the unique monic generator of this ideal (or defined in a way which is equivalent to this definition).

Therefore, $m_A(X)$ divides all polynomials in $I$.

For the characteristic polynomial, Hamilton-Cayley theorem says that the characteristic polynomial belongs to $I$.